What's the difference between a stateful batch and a window with triggers in Beam?
I'm not sure to perfectly understand the difference between a stateful batch in Beam and a window with a trigger by processing time + count with pane discard like:
windowedBatches := beam.WindowInto(s,
            window.NewGlobalWindows(), beam.PCollection(deleteBuckets),
            beam.Trigger(trigger.Repeat(trigger.AfterCount(datastore.MultiEntityWriteLimit))),
            beam.Trigger(trigger.Repeat(trigger.AfterProcessingTime().PlusDelay(b.config.DatastoreBatchInterval))),
            beam.PanesDiscard(),
        )

Can you explain it to me?
